# Php Soap request - UnSupported Media Type

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm trying to use SOAPClient in PHP to get some values from a function.  I've created the code, however, I'm getting the error "UnSupported Media Type".

I've tried researching this issue and found the SOAP version or Content-type in the header could be the issue.

What I'd like to know, is how can I set the SOAP version and the Content-type in the header using the code below.

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {
    header("Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
    $client = new SoapClient(
        "https://www1.gsis.gr/wsaade/RgWsPublic2/RgWsPublic2?WSDL", 
        array("trace" => true, 'exceptions' => 1));
    //    $client->__getTypes();
    //    $client->__getFunctions();

    //    $result = $client->functionName();

    $params = new SoapVar('
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><env:Envelope 
xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns
:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity- 
secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2Service" 
xmlns:ns3="http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2">
<env:Header>
  <ns1:Security>
       <ns1:UsernameToken>
           <ns1:Username>******</ns1:Username>
           <ns1:Password>******</ns1:Password>
     </ns1:UsernameToken>
  </ns1:Security>
   </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
  <ns2:rgWsPublic2AfmMethod>
     <ns2:INPUT_REC>
        <ns3:afm_called_by/>
        <ns3:afm_called_for>******</ns3:afm_called_for>
     </ns2:INPUT_REC>
  </ns2:rgWsPublic2AfmMethod>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>', XSD_ANYXML);

    $result = $client->__soapCall('rgWsPublic2AfmMethod', array($params));
    highlight_string($client->__getLastRequest());
}
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    die("SOAP Fault:<br />fault code: {$fault->faultcode}, fault string: 
{$fault->faultstring}");
}
```

Comment: Have you had any 

    [error_rec] => stdClass Object
         (
             [error_code] => GEN_OTHER_EXCEPTION
             [error_descr] => Σοβαρό πρόβλημα στη βάση δεδομένων
         )
It is rather strange, as my Postman call works fine, but your code returns this.

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to answer, but here's how to consume this service. It's a service that returns info about a business from the greek tax authority. $AFMcalledby is the vat number of the caller, $AFMcalledfor the VAT number of interest, and username/password you get by registering with the service.

```
function checkVATGR($username,$password,$AFMcalledby="",$AFMcalledfor)
{
    $client = new SoapClient( "https://www1.gsis.gr/wsaade/RgWsPublic2/RgWsPublic2?WSDL",array('trace' => true, 'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2) );


    $authHeader = new stdClass();
    $authHeader->UsernameToken=new stdClass();
    $authHeader->UsernameToken->Username = "$username";
    $authHeader->UsernameToken->Password = "$password";
    $Headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $authHeader,TRUE);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($Headers);

    $result = $client->rgWsPublic2AfmMethod(
        array("INPUT_REC" => array(
            'afm_called_by'=>"$AFMcalledby",
            'afm_called_for'=>"$AFMcalledfor"
            ))
        );

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Είσαι απλά γίγαντας!

Answer (score 3):

We can use the `soap_version` option to ensure the request uses SOAP version 1.2:

```php
new SoapClient(
    "https://www1.gsis.gr/wsaade/RgWsPublic2/RgWsPublic2?WSDL",
    [
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
        "trace" => true,
        "exceptions" => 1,
    ]
)
```